# ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error : check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''details'

Tags: mysql

#here is my query

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'details' (
'id' int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
'name' varchar(200) NOT NULL,
'email' varchar(200) NOT NULL,
'gender' varchar(200) NOT NULL,
'address' longtext NOT NULL,
'username' varchar(30) NOT NULL,
'password' varchar(30) NOT NULL,
'verify' tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY ('id')
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Comment: Study carefully the quote chars usage - what char for what purposes must be used.

Comment: can you tell me where can I possible study  and what was my mistake so that I learn and grow , that would be much helpful thank you

Comment: [Literal Values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/literals.html), [Schema Object Names](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html)

Comment: Try "sql tutorial" in google and - yes - w3schools is very much acceptable for beginners (against to contrary believe in this community)

Comment: On  [MySQL Tutorial](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/) you can find very useful tutorials

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Replace names of columns with back ticks.

String use normal single quotes chars.

So:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `details` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
`gender` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
`address` longtext NOT NULL,
`username` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`password` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`verify` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Comment: None of object name needs in quoting - so backticks are excess and can be removed at all in this case.